# What happens if a company you hold short merges with another company?

Tags: stocks, income-tax, shorting-securities, corporate-acquisition

I know how mergers (typically) work when you're long a company, you simply get shares in the merged company equal to your previous market value. But what happens if you hold a short position?

The reason I ask is because this scenario recently happened to me, and I'm seeing a confusing closed position on my tax form. It looks like the old position is treated as a realized gain/loss before converting to the new position?

Comment: http://wiki.fool.com/Taxes_on_My_Short_Sale_Investment#Considerations

Comment: So just to be clear, you were short the pre-M company and you are still short, without any discussions or decisions on your part, the post-M company?  Just so I understand, what sort of merger was it - was it a qualified reorg (so-called "tax-free merger") or was it a taxable sale?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have anything definitive, but in general positions in a company are not affected materially by what is called a [corporate action](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/corporateaction.asp). "Corp Actions" can really be anything that affects the details of a stock. Common examples are a ticker change, or exchange change, IPO (ie a new ticker), doing a split, or merging with another ticker.

All of these events do not change the total value of people's positions. If a stock splits, you might have more shares, but they are worth less per share. A merger is quite similar to a split. The old company's stock is converted two the new companies stock at some ratio (ie 10 shares become 1 share) and then converted 1-to-1 to the new symbol.

[Shorting a stock that splits](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/020314/stock-splits-closer-look-its-effects.asp) is no different. You shorted 10 shares, but after the split those are now 100 shares, when you exit the position you have to deliver back 100 "new" shares, though dollar-for-dollar they are the same total value.

I don't see why a merger would affect your short position. The only difference is you are now shorting a different company, so when you exit the position you'll have to deliver shares of the new company back to the brokerage where you "borrowed" the shares you shorted.